# Why is using PureComponent bad to use for the App component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I started reading about PureComponent's in React, and it's not really clear to me why you would not use it for a parent where the child is not pure.

Perfect example, most apps I've seen wrap everything in an `App` component.  This has no state usually, and I use lifecycle methods on it to do various setup stuff (google analytics, etc).  So it initially sounds like it's ok for a PureComponent.

BUT I've read it's unsafe to use it if child components are not pure ([Should I use React.PureComponent everywhere?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42756354/should-i-use-react-purecomponent-everywhere)).  Which, of course, is the case since everything is wrapped in the `App` component.  I'm just not sure why the child components will potentially not get re-rendered correctly.  What type of situation will you run into if you do this?

Comment: Care to give a minimal code example that helps to clarify what you mean?

Comment: Maybe this can help you. https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/759383530120110080 ?